# $\exists t\in \mathbb{R}, t>0$ such that $v_t = x - ty \ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

The following fact is something I have seen being used in proofs of the Perron-Frobenius theorem:

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n, x>0, y\neq 0$. Then $\exists t\in \mathbb{R}, t>0$ such that $v_t = x - ty \ge 0$ where $v_t$ has atleast one entry equal to $0$.

I do not manage to prove this fact on my own. Any tips?

Clarification:
If $x = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$, by $x>0$ I mean that $\forall i, x_i > 0$. $x\geq 0$ is defined likewise. When I say $x$ has at least one entry equal to 0, I mean $\exists i$, such that $x_i = 0$.

Comment: If $x\in\Bbb R^n$, what does $x>0$ mean?  And does $v_t\ge 0$ mean "$v_t$ has at least one entry equal to $0$"?

Comment: Ted Shifrin, I edited the question. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Is this even correct? If all your entries in $y$ are strictly negative for example (which you allow by only saying $y \neq 0$), then $- t y$ has strictly positive entries, so $x - t y > 0$ for $t > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $t>0$ the components with $y_i \le 0$ are "no problem". We now look at the differences $x_i-ty_i$ for all the components $i$ such that $y_i >0$. Those are only finitely many components. Choose $t_i$ such that $x_i -t_iy_i=0$ which is possible by setting $t_i = \frac{x_i}{y_i}$. Then we have $x_i-ty_i >0$ for all $t < t_i$. If we then take $t_0= \min{\{t_i: i \text{ such that } y_i>0\}}$ We have $x-ty \ge 0$ and there is one component $=0$ - namely the one with minimal $t_i$.

However, as MXXZ pointed out, this all only works if there is a component $y_i>0$. If $y \le 0$ the components of $x-ty$ are all bigger or equal to the components of $x$ and we don't necessarily have a component $=0$.

Comment: What if we assume that $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent? Does that change anything? That is the only assumption I discarded from the proof, since I did not see it having any effect.

Comment: JustANoob, where did linear independence come in here? Linear dependence would mean that all the $t_i$ are equal, no?

Comment: I'm just confused. I agree with your and @MXXZ 's answer, I just could not believe that the proof was wrong. Now I checked another source where the positivity of $t$ is not assumed, they just claim $t \in \mathbb{R}$ exists. Should I delete this question?

Comment: No, there's no reason to delete the question. It has a good answer and you've understood what's going on.